# Can we define functions in H2 such that it takes in parameter values

Tags: jooq

I'm running unit tests on in-memory h2 and dev on postgres.

Postgres functions can be mocked easily by

```
CREATE ALIAS ST_GeomFromEWKT FOR "com.test.Functions.ST_GeomFromEWKT";
```

But custom JOOQ generated function do not work since they are called with written params

```
select id, name from my_custom_function(p_id := 1);
```

H2 requires

```
select id, name from my_custom_function(1);
```

Can this be unified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling that function using the `SQLDialect.POSTGRES` dialect on your H2 database. Switch to `SQLDialect.H2` and it should work for simple functions that can be kept compatible.